# Why do I have to keep using `source ~/.profile` to get settings in place?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I have a couple of bash scripts that I want to make sure runs by default and I'm currently storing them in `~/.profile` on my mac. Is that the wrong place to be storing them? I've heard of others and tried them (like `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, etc), but they don't seem to be working.

What is the difference between all of these and which one do I put the scripts in so that it configures on runtime and I don't have to call `$ source ~/.profile` every time I open the terminal?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
                     +-----------------+
                     |                 |
interactive shell -->|  ~/.bashrc      |
                     |                 |
                     +-----------------+
```

`interactive shell` will source `~/.bashrc` automatically.

Take a look at [Should the .bashrc in the home directory load automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953005/should-the-bashrc-in-the-home-directory-load-automatically/9954208#9954208)

Comment: I'll try this. What is the difference between the login shell and the others?

Comment: An interactive shell is one you run inside a terminal; that is, both stdin and stdout point to the terminal's file descriptors. 99% of the shells you work with will be run as an interactive shell.

Comment: How do I make sure that I'm running interactive and not another one? It seems like I'm running another one.

Comment: @locoboy. Append `source ~/.bashrc` to `~/.bashrc_profile` manually.

Comment: I'm not sure that the ASCII box-and-arrow diagram is helpful.

Answer (score 18):

If both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile` exist, bash only reads `~/.bash_profile` when it is invoked as an interactive login shell.

https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html:

> **Invoked as an interactive login shell, or with --login**
>
> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.
>
> [...]
>
> **Invoked as an interactive non-login shell**
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists.

`~/.profile` is also used by other shells.

Terminal and iTerm open new shells as login shells by default (by executing something like `login -pf $USER`), but many GNU/Linux terminal applications open new shells as non-login shells. OS X users often use `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 9):

I did these to rectify the problem:

```
cat .bash_profile >> .profile
rm .bash_profile
```

the alternative is:

```
echo "source ~/.profile" >> .bash_profile
```

Answer (score 6):

Make sure if you do `source ~/.profile` in your `.bashrc` that you comment out or remove any commands (in `.profile`) to call or source `.bashrc` in your `.profile` or it will loop forever and you will never get a prompt.

Answer (score 3):

Different setups of bash will automatically source different files depending on their configuration. The nearly universal file that is always sourced is `~/.bashrc` - this is a bash core thing that it will load this file. In that file, you should add your line to `source ~/.profile` and you'll be good to go!

-Edit-

From my Linux and my colleague's Mac:

```
$ echo "echo hello" >> ~/.profile
$ echo "source ~/.profile" >> ~/.bashrc
$ bash
Hello
$
```

Comment: I double-checked the solution on a colleague's mac, and posted. At this point, can you provide any insight to what is happening on your machine? If you could run and post ls -l ~/.bashrc, ls -l ~/.profile, cat ~/.bashrc, cat ~/.profile

Comment: .bashrc is only sourced if the shell is interactive and *not* a login shell. By convention, .bashrc is called from `~/.bash_login` but this ain't necessarily so... so you can't count on .bashrc being called. See the link in @kev's post.

Comment: I guess I still need more clarification- the impression from the question is that @locoboy is running this from terminal in osx, which would imply he's indeed using an interactive shell.

Comment: Or, he should move all his scripts from ~/.profile to ~/.bashrc. I had considered posting that answer, but thought this to be more reasonable.

Comment: He might run them from a terminal in OSX, OTOH, if he logged in to the same box via ssh, he would then be launching bash as a login shell, therefore .bashrc would not run, unless .bashrc was called by .bash_login.

Comment: "Learning the bash Shell" by Newham & Rosenblatt covers the whole bash startup process. Their coverage is the second section of Chapter 3 in my copy of the 3rd edition. ".bashrc" typically doesn't run for a login shell, only for sub-shells.

Comment: @BartonChittenden That is very possible- in which case, we need a bit more information on what the problem is before downvoting answers.