# Understanding code that fixed an issue with .profile

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

Ok so I had a problem that is now fixed. I was trying to add a path in my `.profile` but it would only work if I'd source my `.profile` every time a new terminal was open. It forgot about the new path every time I exited terminal. Found a solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320885/why-do-i-have-to-keep-using-source-profile-to-get-settings-in-place).

What I did to fix it was

```
echo "source ~/.profile" >> .bash_profile
echo "source ~/.profile" >> .bashrc
```

My question is, I am still not done installing programs that need a path added to `.profile`, so after I add those paths, will I need to run the above code again?

I am not really sure what it is doing. I know it's copying the content of `.profile` to the other two, but don't know if as text or telling it to go to `.profile` after it's done going through them.

I couldn't comment on the post that helped me because I dont have the reputation necessary to do it. Thanks!

Comment: no. All commands from .profile will be executed from now when opening a bash. Doing it once again could be harmful: adding twice to the path, etc...

Comment: `~/.profile` is for login shells, `~/.bashrc` is for interactive shells, see: `man bash | sed '/^FILES$/,/^$/!d'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You don't need to execute the code again after adding more paths to `.profile`.