# Appending bash alias to .bashrc doesn't work

Tags: bash, alias

I want to create a alias of my **`cd command`**. I have created the .bashrc file and append the command **`cd ......`** to it. (Since the file was newly created, it just has this one line that I added).

After that, only after I typed `. ~/.bashrc`, can the alias works. If I close the terminal and open it again, I need to retype `. ~/.bashrc`.

It's really annoying to do this every time. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thank you so much for help

Comment: what exactly did you save in the .bashrc file ?

Comment: omg, I forgot to say I aded -alias com='cd ~/desktop/computer'-

Comment: and still, I work on mac os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using OS X, append the alias to `~/.bash_profile`.

You could also add alias to `~/.bashrc`, then add `source ~/.bashrc` to `~/.bash_profile`.

Better yet, put all your aliases in `~/.aliases`, and source it in `~/.bash_profile`.

By default, OS X first sources `/etc/bashrc` (which shouldn't be modified unless absolutely necessary), then sources the user's `~/.bash_profile` at the start of every interactive session.

Answer (score 3):

When you login to linux system, only `~/.profile` will be called:

```
$ cat ~/.profile

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

You need to `source ~/.bashrc` inside `~/.profile` manaully.
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953005/should-the-bashrc-in-the-home-directory-load-automatically/9954208#9954208) to learn more.

---

EDIT:

If you're using `iTerm2` on `mac`, it actually start a login shell by default when open tabs.
But you can change it: <kbd>Preferences > General > Command</kbd>

Comment: My answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/636221/107862) also has some relevant information about shell startup files. But as @BroSlow indicates if this is a normal interactive shell then this shouldn't be the problem.