# Why do I need to update system variables every time I restart?

Tags: bash, macos, npm

I've followed [these instructions](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) to the letter to move my global `npm` directory elsewhere, as I was getting permissions issues.

That kinda-worked, but now I can't use `npm` anywhere unless I input `source ~/.profile` every time I restart, which is a huge pain.

Is that deliberate? Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Everything in `.bash_profile` will be sourced on login.

```
echo . ~/.profile >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Sorry vintnes, that didn't answer my question at all.

Answer (score 0):

The way around it is to read and understand the section of the Bash manual that deals with start-up files, and then take appropriate action.

In the latest edition of the Bash manual, this seems to be in [section 6.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files). The version that ships with macOS is probably older, but there has not been much change in this area lately.

My guess would be that you have a ~/.bash_profile file which takes precedence over ~/.profile, but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953005/should-the-bashrc-in-the-home-directory-load-automatically/9954208#9954208) has an answer with a nice graphical flow. It might make sense to source in /etc/profile

This [link](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html) talks about the different startup files of bash. You can `source ~/.profile` in one of the start up files automatically rather than type it manually as you are now.

Depending on if you want it to [source at login or new terminal window](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc) put it in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`

This [link](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile) has a good breakdown of the different files as well.